# PHP - MySQL Like Operation Containing XML Tag

Tags: php

I have a Select Query written in Toad it works well and returns me data as well

Example :

```
SELECT A.shareId,A.creator,A.accessType,
        COUNT(DISTINCT B.user) as userCount
        FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B ON A.shareId = B.shareId
        WHERE A.object LIKE '%<count>10</count>%'
        GROUP BY A.shareId
        ORDER BY userCount DESC;
```

Same query I am trying to use in my `PHP` code then it doesn't return me any data.
Is this because of `LIKE` operation I am performing in Incorrect?

Comment: what is your both  table name, its A or B

Comment: Table Names are  A and B

Comment: Query Statement in PHP $SQL = "SELECT A.shareId,A.creator,A.accessType, COUNT(DISTINCT B_user.user) as userCount FROM A LEFT JOIN B_user ON A.shareId = B_user.shareId WHERE A.object like '%&lt;portletid>" .$portletId. "&lt;/portletid>%' GROUP BY A.shareId ORDER BY userCount DESC";

Comment: @Virat try with `&lt;/portletid&gt;`

Comment: @FaresM. It didnt work

Comment: addSlashes() worked out :) Thanks for your time guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addslashes() function returns a string with backslashes in front of predefined characters.

The predefined characters are:

single quote (')
double quote (")
backslash ()
NULL
Tip: This function can be used to prepare a string for storage in a database and database queries.